# In Qt creator application not compiling with static library in ubuntu

Tags: qt

In Ubuntu Qt creator ,Im trying to build application using the static library,while i try to build the main app its showing following error

```
TDecTop.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `TComAPS::createSaoParam()'
File not Found
.
.
.
```

this function defined inside the static library but the static library included ...

I included static library as follow (at top of the .pro )

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Lib$${COMSATLIB} -lTLibCommon

LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Lib$${DECSATLIB} -lTLibDecoder
```

and how to manage multiple project in Qt creator as like as VS2008

Comment: Can you post what the variables are?

Comment: I solved my problem by rearranging the build order of static library....